# Issue with http call being cancelled by chrome

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I have a rxjs pipeline with two http calls and I have an issue with chrome cancelling one of my http requests..

Here is the rxjs pipeline and the corresponding html:

from the component:

```
  userCtrl = new FormControl();
  ...

  private initAutocomplete() {
    const existingIds$: Observable<number[]> = this.contactService
      .search()
      .pipe(
        map(contacts => contacts.map(c => Number(c.user.uid)))
      );

    this.userSearchResults$ = this.userCtrl
      .valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        filter((name: string) => name.length > 2),
        mergeMap((name: string) =>
          this.contactService.autocomplete(this.buildSearchParams(name))
            .pipe(
              //Causes a canceled http request!!
              withLatestFrom(existingIds$),
              map(([searchItems, existingIds]: [UserSearchItem[], number[]]) =>
                searchItems.filter(
                  (value: UserSearchItem) => !existingIds.includes(value.id))
              )
            )
        )
      );
  }
```

from the html

```
  <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
    <mat-option
      *ngFor="let user of userSearchResults$ | async"
      [value]="user.fullname"
      (onSelectionChange)="handleSelect(user)"
    >
      {{ user.fullname }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
```

from the service:

```
  autocomplete(params: UserSearchParams): Observable<UserSearchItem[]> {
    return this.http.post<UserSearchItem[]>(`${this.apiPrefix}/user/autocomplete`, params);
  }

  search(): Observable<Contact[]> {
    return this.http.post<Contact[]>(`${this.apiPrefix}/bookmarks_user/search`, {});
  }
```

Can someone please tell me how to find out what could cause my **search** request to be cancelled by chrome ?

Comment: Has the cancelled request something to do with the `withLastestFrom()` operator?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the stream formulation. Are you sure the HTTP requests are structured correctly? Are you able to send a successful request individually?

Comment: Hello @MichaelD Thanks for the comment. What do you mean by _structured correctly_ ?

Comment: @MichaelD I can confirm that when I send the *search* request individually, the issue does not occur.

Comment: Another idea: could it be the `async` pipe cancelling the request?

Comment: I see neither the `withLatestFrom` nor the `async` cancelling the requests.

Comment: Silly question, but how do you know chrome is cancelling the request?

Comment: @BizzyBob I see the canceled request in the network tab of devtools.